# Understanding 「一番おいしい」

Tags: grammar, i-adjectives

## Why is 一番おいしい grammatical?

The phrase 一番おいしい means "number one delicious" or "the most delicious". But 一番 is a noun and おいしい is an い-adjective, and as far as I know

> (Noun)(い-adjective)

isn't grammatical in Japanese, right? So is this a special case where 一番おいしい should just be thought of as a single い-adjective which means something like "number-one-most-delicious", rather than a noun merged with an い-adjective?

## Understanding why 世界の一番おいしい isn't grammatical

From a [Cure Dolly video](https://youtu.be/OiKgudW9xB8) on the usage of the で particle, it's stated that

> このラーメンは世界の一番おいしい

is grammatically incorrect, since (in the narrator's own words):

> Japanese words only modify words that come after them.
>
> They can't modify words that come before them.
>
> And because -no can't modify "oishii",
>
> it can only modify "raamen", which is another noun,
>
> and because "raamen" is on the wrong side of it, we can't actually use that.

But isn't 一番 a noun? So couldn't we parse this as

> (世界の一番)(おいしい)

where (世界の一番) is modifying (おいしい)?

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: For your first question: 一番 can also be an adverb, as is the case here. For the second question, and here I only have an assumption, hence only a comment: I think the difference is fundamentally the same as between 学生は学校で遊んでいる and 学生は学校の遊んでいる. There is just something missing at the end of the latter.

Comment: naruto: I read your other post that shows how adverbs can modify adjectives, and after learning from @Kaskade (and also your post) that 一番 can be used adverbally, I understand how 一番おいしい makes sense as (adverb)(i-adjective). Moreover, (世界の一番) makes sense as a noun phrase, but since it's not an adverb, it can't modify (おいしい).  So everything is clear to me now!